# Есть ли функции для переменных аналогичные по работе int

Tags: php

Приветствую всех вошедших

```
$_GET["id"] = (int)$_GET["id"];
```

Собственно есть htmlspecialchars. Для особых параноиков типа меня есть (int). А есть ли еще команды аналогичные (int) которые влияют на значение переменной? Допустим какая ни будь

```
$_GET["id"] = (abcdeабвгд)$_GET["id"]; // оставляем только буквы
```

p.s. если нет, то так и скажите

Comment: preg_match универсальный вариант   
Только он не для параноиков, а для людей думающих о безопасности данных, полученных со стороны пользователя.

Comment: еще, как вариант, меньше универсальности, но уже готовое: [filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)

Comment: можно всяких разных написать ) преобразования типа, как ты написал int, экранирование, кроме htmlspecialchars есть еще  mysql_real_escape_string($user), которая работает только с кавычками. если нужно тебе только буквы, используй регулярное выражение, как выше написали.

Comment: В тысячный раз можно сказать, что используйте PDO и многие параноидальные психозы вас покинут. ))

Comment: @deonis, а пдо защитит от локального инклуда ? Лучше проверять на всякий пожарный все пришедшие от пользователя данные.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а приведение типов это защита?

Comment: Что ж не в ответах? 2 последних комента - опять наводят на бездну незнания. Все выше написанное приме к сведению.

Comment: @deonis, если считать проверку пришедших данных защитой, то да :)